# Httparty - sharing values across classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have 2 services which make api calls, they do different things but both have the same httparty settings at the top of the class, whats the best way to share these settings?  Using inheritance or some other coding mechanism?

e.g.

```
class FirstService
  include HTTParty
  format :json
  base_uri: "url"
  basic_auth
  default_timeout 360
```

and

```
class SecondService
  include HTTParty
  format :json
  base_uri: "url"
  basic_auth
  default_timeout 360
```

Can I create a top level class and somehow inherit these values to both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that yes. I would suggest to only do that if the service have an inheritance between each other (Animal is the logical parent class of Cat and Dog, but not of Cat and Car). Otherwise, I'd suggest using a module to include in both:

```
 module HTTPartyReady
  include HTTParty
  format :json
  base_uri: "url"
  basic_auth
  default_timeout 360
 end

class FirstService
  include HTTPPartyReady
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in `config/settings.yml` like this:

```
development:
  base_uri:  "url"
  default_timeout 360

test:
  base_uri:  "url"
  default_timeout 360

production:
  base_uri:  "url"
  default_timeout 360
```

And then in your app or whereever you use these values access these values with:

```
Rails.application.settings.base_uri
```